# How do the same function for pytorch expand_as in keras

Tags: python, keras, pytorch

pytorch code:

```
att_h = att_h.unsqueeze(1).expand_as(att)
```

att_h shape is (10,512)

att shape is (10,196,512)

Keras code:

```
K.expand_dims(att_h, 1).expand_as(att)
```

Got error:
    'Tensor' object has no attribute 'expand_as'

Not sure how to do the same thing in keras.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any inbuilt function in Keras as such. But you can achieve the same result using : `np.reshape`.

So you can :

```
K.expand_dims(att_h,1).reshape(att.shape)
```